# How to use a different diff command for Emacs and Shell (in terminal)?

Tags: shell, svn, emacs, colors, diff

I'm using the graphical Emacs-w32 launched from a Cygwin terminal (on Windows) for all editing, and Zsh (in a MinTTY) for running commands.

I've setup up `diff-cmd = colordiff` in `~/.subversion/config`, and, while that makes nice colors in the terminal (for `svn log`), that causes the problem of **adding color escape codes** in the output, when diff'ing in Emacs, leading to **uncolorized, unreadable diffs in Emacs**.

What would be the most sensible fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution found in the EmacsWiki:

> if you use colordiff in svn, maybe you need this:

```
(add-hook 'diff-mode-hook 
    '(lambda () 
        (require 'ansi-color)
        (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))))
```

Source: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VersionControl

By the way: searching the web for 'emacs svn colordiff' produced this as a top 5 hit...